# NSFetchRequest does not read updated rows

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

the data gets downloaded and written in core data in background thread with (child/parent context)
using NSFetchRequest the first time reading is ok. after a refresh, i pull the data from core data and update it with new values. again reading the data NSFetchRequest in main thread/main context. it still returns the old values. i have checked the core data table and it has the new values in it. and i can see the updated data after killing and restarting the app.

what am i doing wrong?

ps: sorry cant post the code. its a huge project. all other parts of the project based on core data works perfectly. only this part getting on my nerve. :-(

Comment: Without some code, it will be very hard to offer help.

Comment: i have learned that using objects from main conext on the UI remains unchanged, even the objects are updated in background context. so i have updated the rows on the main thread and everything works fine now. it's ok in this part because the number of objects does not exceed 10 rows. how can i release those object from main context or update them in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that the fetchresult controller retrieving objects on the main thread and i had to group on more than one attribute and calculate date for current time zone. so i had allthis done in background thread. once again i learned that core data objects are not thread safe!